# Inner product of vectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, complex-numbers

While reading Shankar Ramamurti's book on Principles of Quantum Mechanics, p. 10, I came across the following lines under the concept of inner product of two vectors (in terms of orthonormal basis):

> $$\langle V|W \rangle= \sum_{i} {v_i}^{*} w_i \tag{1.2.5}$$
>   [...] You can now appreciate the first axiom; but for the complex conjugation of the components of the first vector, $\langle V|V \rangle$ would not even be real, not to mention positive.

The first axiom under discussion is the skew-symmetry of vectors: $\langle V|W \rangle={\langle W|V \rangle}^{*}$. The trouble I am facing is understanding the phrase "*$\langle V|V \rangle$ would not even be real*"

The phrase tells me that the inner product $\langle V|V \rangle$ is not real. The axiom—positive semidefiniteness—tells me otherwise. Am I misinterpreting the language here or is my understanding of the axiom askew?

Answer (score 4):

You missed part, it says,

> **but for** the complex conjugation of the components of the first vector, ⟨V|V⟩ would not even be real, not to mention positive. [emphasis added].

Because the first term is conjugated ($v_i^\star$), we know that each term $v_i^\star v_i$ is real and nonnegative so the sum $\left<V|V\right>$  will also real and positive (assuming V is not the zero vector).

> The phrase tells me that the inner product above is not real.

In general, if there's no other restriction on two vectors V and W which have complex elements, then you are correct, it's possible their inner product is not real.

**Edit:** you edited your question to say,

> The phrase tells me that the inner product ⟨V|V⟩ is not real.

No, it says if you didn't take the conjugate of the first term in each product, it might not be real.

Since we do conjugate the first term, the inner product of a complex-valued vector with itself will be real.

Comment: I misinterpreted the lines. I could not comprehend what _"but for"_ was trying to suggest. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I was kind of wondering if this should be migrated to English Language SE. "But for" is a bit to poetical to be put in a textbook for scientists.

Comment: I was going to post it there. But I decided to wait here.

Comment: Reason being that people here would better understand the context of discussion.

Comment: This phrasing is the kind of thing some non-native speakers will get a habit of saying, that sounds really weird to native speakers. One former boss of mine always used "for" instead of "because", making it sound like she was always reciting poetry.

Comment: @ThePhoton "But for ..." is perfectly standard English.  I would think that non-native-speakers would have a harder time with it.   If it sounds weird I would complain to your high school.

Comment: @garyp, it's usually only seen in literary or poetic contexts (or song lyrics). It's standard English but most native speakers would say something like "if it weren't for..." or "if there wasn't..." much more often.

Comment: Putting aside the "is it standard?" debate, "but for" means "were it not for".

Comment: @J.G. which is still very formal/stilted usage. Probably okay for academic writing.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, I bet you're not the first or last reader of Ramamurti that got tripped up there.